# VSCode Python 3+ Microsoft extension doesn't warn about passing in a parameter of a different type

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode Python 3+ with Microsoft's python extension. I can do this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

def my_func(p: Point):
    p.x = 5
    p.y = 5

def this_func_should_warn():
    # my_func takes a Point, but I am passing in 5. I don't get any complaint here.
    my_func(5)
```

PyCharm catches this, but VSCode does not. I am wondering if I need to enable something, or is this a known problem for this VSCode extension.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Comment: Thanks I am using mypy now.

Comment: try using pylance plugin for vscode, you can enable strict linting https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance